# Factory - A value of type 'B' can't be returned from the constructor 'A.factoryConstructor' because it has a return type of 'A<T>'

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, factory

I have this simplified code:

```dart
enum Types {
  b,
  c,
}

class A<T> {
  A();

  factory A.factoryConstructor(Types type) {
    switch(type) {
      case Types.b:
        return B(); // <- A value of type 'B' can't be returned from the constructor 'A.factoryConstructor' because it has a return type of 'A<T>'
      case Types.c:
        return C(); // <- A value of type 'C' can't be returned from the constructor 'A.factoryConstructor' because it has a return type of 'A<T>'
    }
  }
}

class B extends A<bool> {}

class C extends A<String> {}
```

And I get the error:

```
A value of type 'B' can't be returned from the constructor 'A.factoryConstructor' because it has a return type of 'A<T>'
```

(same for `C`).

I can fix it by writing:

```dart
      case Types.b:
        return B() as A<T>;
      case Types.c:
        return C() as A<T>;
```

But the list can implementation can be quite long (`D`, `E`, `F`, and so on). I was wondering if there was a better method than writing `as A<T>` everywhere?

Comment: Try changing your declaration of `B` to `class B<bool> extends A<bool> {}`

Comment: @RichardHeap That would be the same thing as `class B<T> extends A<T>` except that the type parameter would be named `bool`, which would be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can fix it by writing:
>
> ```dart
>       case Types.b:
>         return B() as A<T>;
>       case Types.c:
>         return C() as A<T>;
> ```
>
> But the list can implementation can be quite long (`D`, `E`, `F`, and
> so on). I was wondering if there was a better method than writing `as A<T>` everywhere?

Casting would allow your code to compile, but it'd be an unsafe fix because an `A<T>` constructor must always return an `A<T>`.  If a caller did `A<String>.factoryConstructor(b)`, you'd attempt to cast a `B` (a subtype of `A<bool>`) to an `A<String>`, which would fail and throw a `TypeError` exception at runtime.

You'd be better off using a `static` method so that you can specify a different return type:

```dart
static A<dynamic> factoryConstructor(Types type) {
  switch (type) {
    case Types.b:
      return B();
    case Types.c:
      return C();
  }
}
```